# How can I stop my table view cells loading their subviews multiple of times in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using FontLabel in the view cells of the table.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    FontLabel *author_name = [[FontLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(58, 10, 217, 16) fontName:@"MyriadPro-Bold" pointSize:12.0f];
    author_name.numberOfLines = 1;
    author_name.text = [dummyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    author_name.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.580 green:0.776 blue:0.329 alpha:1.000];
    author_name.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [cell addSubview:author_name];
    return cell;

}
```

But the label is loaded multiple times. I can see that it is getting bolder and bolder. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `addSubview`, it's not removing the old view. remember that cells are reused so the view you added in the last iteration is still there.

You should instead subclass `UITableViewCell` so that you can add a `UILabel` to it.

**Edit:**

Or you can do

```
author_name.tag = 10;
```

and then

```
FontLabel *author_name = (FontLabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
```

when you want to retrieve it.

Comment: Not necessarily. There's a much easier solution for this.

Comment: Btw `[cell.accessoryView viewWithTag:10]` won't return the label, since OP adds it to the cell itself, and not its accessory view.

Comment: No, you can't. But I don't see anywhere in the question that OP wants it.

Comment: hmm... so how do you handle `author_name.text = [dummyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`?

Comment: that's true. (but nevertheless, this problem arises from the OP's design being flawed.)

Comment: I moved the initialization of the cell in a CommentCell. Now it seems fine.